# Split pandas Series rows containing multiline strings into separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, split, series

I have a pandas Series that is filled with strings like this:

```
In:    
s = pd.Series(['This is a single line.', 'This is another one.', 'This is a string\nwith more than one line.'])

Out:
0                        This is a single line.
1                          This is another one.
2    This is a string\nwith more than one line.
dtype: object
```

How can I split all rows in this Series that contain the linebreak character `\n` into rows of their own? What I would expect is:

```
0      This is a single line.
1        This is another one.
2            This is a string
3    with more than one line.
dtype: object
```

I know that I can split each row by the linebreak character with

```
s = s.str.split('\n')
```

which gives

```
0                        [This is a single line.]
1                          [This is another one.]
2    [This is a string, with more than one line.]
```

but this only breaks the string within the row, not into rows of their own for each token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop over each string in each row to create a new series:

```
pd.Series([j for i in s.str.split('\n') for j in i])
```

It might make more sense to do this on the input rather than creating a temporary series, e.g.:

```
strings = ['This is a single line.', 'This is another one.', 'This is a string\nwith more than one line.']
pd.Series([j for i in strings for j in i.split('\n')])
```